# Mysql 5.7.19 ( on Ubuntu 17) Restart automatically after some days

Tags: mysql, 17.04

I am facing an issue related to Mysql 5.7.19 ( on Ubuntu 17).
Mysql restarts after 2 or 3 days automatically.
Whenever it restarts following lines are available in syslog.

```
Aug 10 11:52:19 db1 kernel: [787345.027934] audit: type=1400 audit(1502346139.942:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3381/task/19686/mem" pid=3381 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=113 ouid=113
Aug 10 11:52:19 db1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 10 11:52:19 db1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 10 11:52:19 db1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 10 11:52:20 db1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 10 11:52:20 db1 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 10 11:52:20 db1 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This was an issue with mysql release which is fixed with mysql 5.7.21 release. Here is bug link. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79243&thanks=3&notify=67